# Efficiently parsing and writing to a file in Java

Tags: java, string

I have a file that has no new line characters. I want a new line character every 160 characters.

To do this, I read the file, and then do:

```
String newLine = "";
int lineSize = 160;
char[] line = new char[lineSize];
while (rEntrada.read(line) > 0) {
   newLine = new String(line);
   String parsedLine = parseLine(newLine, date);
   fw.write(parsedLine);
}
```

where parseLine takes care of some extra parsing of the line. My main question is if doing a "new String" inside a while loop is inefficient or not recommended or if you guys see anything that could be done better in this code. I'm really trying to get better at coding!

Thanks!

Comment: In Java using Strings inside or outside the loop does not matter so much. Strings are immutable, so the only thing you will be saving are references to Strings, which is negligible. You can though, take a look at examples which use StringBuilder.

Comment: Doesn't really matter. Saving references doesn't save you a lot of cycles or memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

- First read the single line.

  ```
  FileReader r = new FileReader(new File("<file-name>"));
  // A buffered reader is fast
  BufferedReader = reader = new BufferedReader(r);
  ```

  ```
  String line = reader.readLine();
  // Also use try-catch blocks!
  ```
- Now iterate over the string and insert a `\n` at every 160<sup>th</sup> position.

  ```
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  int counter = 0;
  ```

  ```
  for (int i=0; i<line.length(); i++){
      sb.append(line.charAt(i));
      counter++;
      if (counter==160){
          sb.append("\n");
          counter = 0;
      }
  }
  ```

  ```
  line = sb.toString();
  ```
- Now you could write this line to the file.

Comment: Couldn't you just start at i=160 and get rid of the `i==0` check?

Comment: It could throw exception if the length of line is greater. But I edited to a new better answer.

Comment: still don't like that, why append one char at a time when you know you're going to append 160 before you append a `\n`?

Comment: Again the same. It's simpler to understand and also we need every char in between the `\n`'s

Answer (score 1):

It looks good to me, the only inefficiency I can see is if `parseLine` could be written better, possibly being passed `line` instead of `newLine`. It depends on what `parseLine` actually does.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at StringBuffer and see if it isn't usable in this case.

[StringBuffer API Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html)

[StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) may also be of interest if you're not multi-threaded.